# Magento Inheriting and Re-Using Template Variables

Tags: xml, layout, templates, magento

Is it possible to pass a variable from a parent template to a child template.  For example, if i wanted to put some repeated HTML in a separate template that was included within a foreach loop in its parent template

```
<?php

foreach ($items as $item)
{
    echo $this->getChildHtml('item_info');
}

?>
```

I would want to be able to access the $item variable within the item_info template.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've split my product list template to a separate file so I can use it in several places.

In the parent template, I do something like:

```
<?PHP
$this->getChild('product_list_list')->setData('products', $_productCollection);
echo $this->getChildHtml('product_list_list'); 
?>
```

In the child template I can do:

```
<?php foreach ($this->products as $_product): ?>
  // display products
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So you should be able to do:

```
$this->getChild('item_info')->setData('item', $item);
```

and then within item_info, access it as

```
$this->item
```

Hope that works for you. Works for me on magento 1.3, but it seems fairly fundamental, so probably common to all versions.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not a new post, but here is a little completion :

you should call getChildHtml with cache attribute at false, such as :

```
$this->getChildHtml('item_info', false);
```

And then, it will work perfectly.

Thank you benlumley